# How can I use solr post tool to index xml?

Tags: xml, solr

I try to execute this command line  below

java -Dc=films -jar exampledocs/post.jar films/films.xml

but I had this error

SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #401 (Authentication required) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/films/update
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Looks like Solr is secured and would not let us in. Try with another user in '-u' parameter
How can I fix that please

I want also to index xlsx files.How can I do that ?

Comment: Looks like your Solr installation requires authentication. Do you need to enter a username/password when you browse to `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/films` ? If so, you'll need to pass those credentials to Solr via the `-u` parameter as indicated in the error message that you included.

Comment: I have this same problem with solr-7.7.3. Just don't know how to find the credentials to use. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass username and password

```
java -Dbasicauth=user:password -Dtype=text/json -Dc=collectionname -jar post.jar D:\data\data.json
```